# Web application no longer restarts automatically on Azure WebApps on TOMCAT server : HTTP 404

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

My applications were working properly on Azure, but after a Microsoft Docker update, they don't all restart automatically.

**I have an HTTP 404**:

[image]

My analysis :

This application was deployed with Microsoft tools

```
az webapp deploy ...
```

in log : /home/DeploymentLogStream/ xxx.log
the application is deployed correctly and it is present on file system

```
...
"Clean deploying to /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/wholesale"}
"Generating deployment script."}
"Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot
"Running deployment command..."}
"Command: \"/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh\""}
"Handling Basic Web Site deployment."}
....
"Requesting site restart"}
"Requesting site restart. Attempt #1"}
"Successfully requested a restart. Attempt #1"}
"Deployment successful. deployer = OneDeploy deploymentPath = OneDeploy
```

In Docker Log file I see an update of Microsoft image :

```
675db21ca06b Extracting 133B / 133B
675db21ca06b Extracting 133B / 133B
675db21ca06b Pull complete   
 Digest: sha256:932deb9018db39b74249774b4206906424f3fea09b791e9318c43316dc695aff
 Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-app-service/tomcat:8.5-jre8_220406005815
Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Minutes and 11 Seconds
Starting container for site  
docker run -d -p 8871:80 --name ..                                                              

Container ... initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

But in Tomcat log File I only see the default ROOT module and not my Web application.
and indeed my app is not copy from /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/wholesale to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/wholesale
[/usr/local/tomcat/webapps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnRel.png)

Redeployment does not change the problem.
Multiple restarts solve the problem but without understanding why.
The workaround is to manually copy the directory from /home to /usr, but next update will remove it.

Someone has an idea to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience with this issue and delayed response here.

Users using the auto-update version of Tomcat on Linux that deploy multiple applications in the webapps directory may see their apps return 404.

You may manually change the version to respective working version:

Tomcat 8.5: **8.5.72**

Tomcat 9.0: **9.0.54**

Tomcat 10.0: **10.0.12**

You may also check [Azure Service Health history](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/service-health-portal-update#health-history-window), notification info.

Kindly let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thx, I'm late too. I was on the latest version 9.0.62 and it didn't work. By switching to 9.0.54 it works now. I will see if it still works with the next deployment

Comment: @TanguyCoueryLTR, Glad it's working! Thanks for the update. If the answer pointed you in the right direction, please consider to accept the answer.